# Specific algorithm in oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

I need to realize SSO system using Oauth2. 
I understand steps in oauth2, but I don't know what's the Specific algorithm in generating an authorize code or an access_token,maybe Hash or something.And I can't find it on the internet

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626575/best-practices-around-generating-oauth-tokens

Answer (score 2):

OAuth 2 specs:

> Access tokens can have different formats, structures, and methods of
>   utilization (e.g., cryptographic properties) based on the resource
>   server security requirements.

The format of the tokens (and authorization codes) are not defined by the specs, so there is no *specific algorithm*.

The specs do require:

> The authorization server MUST ensure that access tokens cannot be
>   generated, modified, or guessed to produce valid access tokens by
>   unauthorized parties.

So, for instance a random UUID makes a fine token. You could also consider [JWT tokens](https://jwt.io/).

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 spec doesn't specify any algorithm or way to generate token value. You can use whatever algorithm, even serial number starts from 1, to generate those token values. You can use more complicated random number generation, encryption, crypto algorithm. Most of them are pretty quick to generate key value, but you need to check how fast current authentication server can generate a key and if it meets your service's requirement.

For example, for token generation in Spring Security, DefaultTokenServices generates access token and refresh token using random UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to implement your own Oauth generator, you can use existing providers like WSO2 API Manager for supporting your system. It is well documented and has many REST APIs for this.

Answer (score 0):

access_token contains the claims. So do authentication of user/client and other validations as mentioned in oauth2 spec. Then if you consider JWT for access_token format then you can use jose4j api for access_token creation which supports JWE and JWS as well.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 does not define a specific method to generate or protect tokens (authorization code, access/refresh token).
You can implement any strong symmetric cryptographic algorithm, so that you can protect or encrypt the token you are sending.

1. If you don't want to check token against database you should have this strong encryption.
2. If it is fine to check token against database you can use a key-value pair, so that you provide key to user and value is stored only in database.